# jQuery.post is sending escaped characters

Tags: php, jquery, json, post, escaping

I have a string created by `recipeBlob = JSON.stringify(recipeData)`. It is a long string but here is a sample of it:

```
"properties":{"Energy":{"val":90.6,"unit":"cal","rdi":"2000"},"Protein":{"val":0.4,"unit":"g","rdi":"50.00000000"},"Fat":{"val":0.6,"unit":"g","rdi":"65.000000000"},"Carbohydrates":{"val":23.3,"unit":"g","rdi":"300.0000000"},"Dietary Fiber":{"val":4.1,"unit":"g","rdi":"25"},"Sugars":{"val":18.8,"unit":"g","rdi":null}
```

which I send via $.post like this:

```
$.post('scripts/save_blob.php', {
            blob : recipeBlob
        });
```

The `$string = $_POST['blob']` that arrives at my PHP script is showing up like this:

```
{\"properties\":{\"Energy\":{\"val\":90.6,\"unit\":\"cal\",\"rdi\":\"2000\"},\"Protein\":{\"val\":0.4,\"unit\":\"g\",\"rdi\":\"50.00000000\"},\"Fat\":{\"val\":0.6,\"unit\":\"g\",\"rdi\":\"65.000000000\"},\"Carbohydrates\":{\"val\":23.3,\"unit\":\"g\",\"rdi\":\"300.0000000\"}
```

When I run `json_decode($string)` it is returning error #4 which is json syntax error.

I don't know at which part of the process the characters are being escaped, which I need to avoid.

Comment: You can use the function `stripslashes` for this I guess...

Comment: Is it a string itself that you are trying to STRINGIFY, or is it a JSON object?

Comment: Does the server have PHP magic quotes on?

Comment: It's a javascript object

Comment: Don't stringify this object, just send it as is, i.e. `blob : recipeData`.

Comment: @Juhana, yes they were on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Juhana provided the most direct answer to the question, PHP magic quotes were turned on on the server, thus automatically escaping quotes.

@dfsq provided the solution I actually used, which is to just send the javascript object without stringifying it. it arrives to the PHP script as an array.